# Xdebug connection breaks instantly in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

Xdebug stopped working in PhpStorm. The connection is lost in less than a second. I connect to Xdebug via SSH. I have attached a video with the bug. I will be grateful for any help.

- PHP 7.3.33
- Xdebug 3.1.5
- PhpStorm 2022.2.3
- Mac OS

[bug video (google disk)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rn8A-1ojObknkWTVfCHVU1651TU37ax5/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: 1) Restart your whole OS (it often helps with such random "stopped working" even if it's not  Windows OS) 2) Enable Xdebug log and try to debug again -- see what it will have there (if it's a "normal" exit or it just dies/process terminated etc). Maybe it's crashing. 3) You can also enable extra logging on PhpStorm end -- to see their side of things: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/troubleshooting-php-debugging.html#c009532e 4) ALWAYS state your versions used (IDE, PHP , Xdebug, OS) -- the version _may_ play a role (in case if it's a known issue).

Comment: So far -- no real clues. 1) Collect Xdebug logs (see if it's a clean session exit or not) 2) Check the IDE logs (`Help | Show Log in XXX`) 3) Just in case (just a thought) -- see if disabling `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | PHP | Debug | Enable '__toString' object view` will make any difference. Other than that: no other ideas from the info provided so far.

Comment: @LazyOne thank you so much! Disabling "Enable '__toString' object view" helped me

Comment: Please try 2022.3 EAP build with the above option ENABLED -- will it work OK for you? There were some improvements/fixes in this area recently. You can have both stable and EAP versions installed at the same time. Just do not open the same project in both of them simultaneously. https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2022/10/phpstorm-2022-3-early-access-2-code-vision/

Comment: Xdebug works on EAP 2022.3 build with the above option enabled.

Answer (score 1):

General approach in troubleshooting here:

1. Enable Xdebug log (most likely will need to restart your web server/php-fpm) and try to debug again. Then check the log to see if it was a clean exit or it just died/process terminated. Maybe Xdebug is crashing.
2. You may also [enable extra logging on PhpStorm end](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/troubleshooting-php-debugging.html#c009532e) to see their side of things. Then you can check the `idea.log` via `PhpStorm | Help | Show Log in XXX`

**P.S.** Just in case: see if disabling `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | PHP | Debug | Enable '__toString' object view` option will make any difference. PhpStorm 2022.2 has implemented this functionality but it looks like not all corner cases may be covered yet.

---

Since disabling the `Enable '__toString' object view` option helped, then please check out the [2022.3 EAP version](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/nextversion/) -- EAP builds have a few tickets fixed in this area.

Since it works OK for you in 2022.3 EAP build then it could be one of these tickets (cannot say which one without knowing the code / seeing the logs etc.):

- [WI-68096](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-68096) -- '__toString' in Debugger triggers custom error handler
- [WI-68622](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-68622) -- Enable '__toString() object view': code that reads from stream ends early under debugger